# Win7 won't discover network printers

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer, printing

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 32-bit on a desktop machine as part of a wired work domain. When I try to add a network printer through the Add Printer option from the Devices and Printers page I get the following problem: I select "Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer" and click Next but on the search page the progress bar completes in under two seconds and no printers are found. It's like it isn't even searching the network. I've been able to add network printers on this system before (although I am now unable to print to any of them).

Anyone got any ideas? It seems like a service may not be running but nothing obvious leaps out in the service manager.

To be clear: I am on a wired LAN, the network printer is also on the wired LAN. I am not attempting to connect to a wireless or local printer.

Comment: mycomputer-->manage-->systemtools-->device manager is your printer visible over there?

Comment: I'm lost, you've said you're on a wired network and then search for wireless printers... Does your machine have wireless?

Comment: I'm looking for a network printer, not a wireless printer. I'm on a wired network. The "Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer" refers to an option in the Add Printer dialogue. The printer does not show up in Device Manager because it is a network printer, not a local printer. All other systems on the LAN can use all network printers. The way the progress bar speeds across in 2 seconds suggests to me that something is wrong in whatever component carries out the network search.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've added network printers before is to navigate in Explorer to the hostname or IP address of the printer.

```
\\printer-name.domain.com\
```

or

```
\\192.168.5.112\
```

as the case may be.

For me anyways, it then shows a printer device being shared. You right-click it and select "Connect to this printer" and allow it to install the drivers.